# How can keep track of affiliated websites

Tags: architecture, e-commerce, affiliate, affiliates

I want developed a website where I will show the products of other websites. I have searched about affiliate marketing and its really working great.

But the issue is,still there are some countries where affiliate marketing is unknown. Few websites provides affiliations.

I want to host website in one of these countries. There are few(5%) websites which provides affiliations, so my questions will be about other (95%) non-affiliated websites or clients.

- If I want to show non-affiliated websites products, Do I need to install some affiliate API in their system(websites) or they will be responsible?
- If they don't want to implement any third party API, they want to add their own system then How much it will reliable. I mean how can I track record of users or customers.
- From technical side, Do I need to add some tracking code on their websites? Like some website provides small scripts?

I will be responsible for application architecture and development, So I need to make clear of these things. I have searched on it but can't found technical articles or information.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

1. If you are already affiliated with a website and they have tracking system then no issues, But if they dont have any then you can use [pixel tracking](https://www.quora.com/How-does-a-tracking-pixel-work) to track your affiliate progress.
2. If you are showing products from websites, To which you are not affiliated yet then get affiliated with them. Or search they are tiedup with a service like [ShareASale](https://www.shareasale.com/) etc.